# Continuity of a function from the reals to the reals that fixes rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ by $x\mapsto x$ if $x$ is rational and $x\mapsto 0$ if $x$ is irratoinal.

Prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $a=0$.

I'm struggling to grasp how to approach this, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true
for any two dense sets of reals
whose union is the reals.

Call these $S$ and $T$,
where
$x \in S \implies f(x) = 0$
and
$x \in T \implies f(x) = x$.

If $f$ were continuous,
then,
for any real $a \ne 0$,
for any $\delta > 0$
there would be a
$\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x- a| < \epsilon
\implies
|f(x)-f(a)| < \delta$.

Now, set $\delta = |a/3|$.
This says that
there is a
$\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x- a| < \epsilon
\implies
|f(x)-f(a)| < |a/3|$.

If $a \in S$,
then $f(a) = 0$.
this means that
there is a
$\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x- a| < \epsilon
\implies
|f(x)| < |a/3|$.
But,
since $T$ is dense,
there is an 
$x \in T$
such that
$|x-a| < |a/3|$.
This means that
$a-|a/3| < x
< a+|a/3|
$,
so that
$|x| > |2a/3|$,
so that
$|f(x)|
=|x|
> |2a/3|
$,
which contradicts
$|f(x)| < |a/3|$.

We get a similar contradiction
if $x \in T$,
which you can work out.

Therefore,
$f(a)$ is not continuous
if $a \ne 0$.

The only case that
$f(a)$ might be continuous
is $a=0$,
and I will let you
work out the proof
in this case.

Answer (score 2):

first to get the idea of the fact that this function is discontinuous at every point other than 0, you can try to use sequential criteria of continuity.

Hint: To check continuity at a rational point say $a$, Use the fact that there exists a sequence of irrational points approaching $a$. and then look at what happens with the image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity means if we force $x$ and $y$ close together we force $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ close together.

If $x \ne 0$ then know matter how close we force $x$ and $y$ together there will be both irrationals and rationals close $x$ and but the differences between $f(rational)$ and $f(irrational)$ will about $x$.  So we aren't forcing them closer than that.

Or more formally:

Let $x \ne 0$

Let's let $x > \epsilon > 0$.

Case 1: $x$ is rational. $f(x) = x > \epsilon$.  For *any* $\delta > 0$ we can always find an irrational $y$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$.  But $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x - 0| = x > \epsilon$.  We can not find a $\delta > 0$ where $|x - y| < \delta$ forces $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.  So $f$ is not contionuous at x.

Case 2: $x$ is irrational:  For any $\delta > 0$ we can always find a rational $r$ such that $x > r > \max(x - \delta, \epsilon)$.  So $|x -r| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(r)| = |0 - r| = r > \epsilon$.  We can not find a $\delta > 0$ where $|x - y| < \delta$ forces $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.  So $f$ is not contionuous at x.